# How to choose particular field of another table as Foreign key of a Table? Sqlite3,Django==2.1

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Student(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    roll = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False,
                            unique=True, primary_key=True)
    contact_no = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=0, blank=False, unique=True)
    objects = UserManager()


class Event(models.Model):
    type_of_event = models.ForeignKey(EventType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    event_date = models.DateField()
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    entry_fee = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard')


class EventParticipants(models.Model):
    event_name = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    participant_roll = models.ForeignKey(
        Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="123")
```

How do I make the `roll` field in the model `Student` as the foreign key in the table `EventParticipants`. By default the `username` field from model `Student` is chosen as the foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) says you can set a **to_field** value in the ForeignKey declaration to any unique field in the target Model.

```
participant_roll = models.ForeignKey(
        Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='roll')
```